# ResolveUrl XSS alternative

Tags: c#, asp.net

After the [research published showing that .aspx routes are vulnerable to reflected XSS](https://blog.isec.pl/all-is-xss-that-comes-to-the-net/), what is the recommended alternative to using `Page.ResolveUrl` or `Control.ResolveUrl`? The linked article doesn't suggest any mitigations.

Summary of the linked research:

- **For .aspx pages (not MVC)**, even if you don't have cookieless sessions enabled, ASP.NET still parses those "special" URL formats such `http://www.example.com/(S(lit3py55t21z5v55vlm25s55))/orderform.aspx`
- it includes them in the page output whenever you use `ResolveUrl`.
- Thus it creates an attack vector where a call like `ResolveUrl( "~/Images/logo.png" )` will inject content of the attacker's choice into your page output, e.g.

```
/(S("onerror="alert`1`"))/Images/logo.png`
```

I've posted one possible answer below but am looking for better ideas.

Note that `ResolveClientUrl` is not a direct replacement since it generates a relative Url, e.g. `../Images/logo.png` unlike `ResolveUrl` which generates a root Url e.g. `/myapp/Images/logo.png`

Comment: Have you found a better solution yet?

Comment: @JanW no, I have not

Comment: We used your suggested HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath.TrimEnd( '/' ) approach and it worked for us. Thanks for sharing and stay safe :)

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to use `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath` instead of the special tilde syntax. So the example from above...

Instead of:

```
ResolveUrl( "~/Images/logo.png" )
```

We would have:

```
HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath.TrimEnd( '/' ) + "/Images/logo.png"
```

Slightly less concise but seems to accomplish the same thing without invoking the ancient "cookieless" route parsing.

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Use `ResolveClientUrl` instead of `ResolveUrl`.
`ResolveClientUrl` will not allow XSS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but `ResolveClientUrl` generates a relative Url, e.g. `../Images/logo.png` so it's not a direct replacement for `ResolveUrl` which generates a root Url e.g. `/myapp/Images/logo.png`